# Java Search Database to Table

Tags: java, database, search, database-connection

I cant search record in database, when I write text to `TextField` `TableModel` is loading but don't search in database and table is clear.

```
private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        

    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(2);
     try {

        File currDir= new File ("Baza.db");
        String sc = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
         sc = sc.substring(0, sc.length());

         String url = "jdbc:sqlite://"+sc;
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         String wyszukaj =" SELECT * FROM WydatkiStale WHERE id_WydatekStaly =?";
         PreparedStatement pst  = conn.prepareStatement(wyszukaj);
         pst.setString(1,"value");
         ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


   jTable3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } 
}
```

[application window view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z20rF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely here:

```
pst.setString(1,"value");
```

You use hardcoded value in every DB query, but you should use dynamically obtained value from `java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt` or from `TextField` content

Comment: `pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());` not working

Comment: Since column is called `id_WydatekStaly` (id prefix) maybe it is numeric? So you probably need to convert `jTextField1.getText()` to number and set like `pst.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText()));` ?

Comment: Yes, column `id_WydatekStaly` was integer, I convert TextField to int and is ok, thanks man!

Comment: Glad to help you, accept the answer if it was useful